# How do I put the Site Contents Tree on a full Page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Currently I have the site contents tree view in my quick launch side bar.  I was hoping to get the same Tree View for Site Contents and put on a main page since my libraries have grown...

People like the view of the Site Contents Tree View, but I need more real estate especially since I am required to have links in the Quick Launch.

Comment: Maybe use the table of contents web part on a separate wiki or publishing page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for "PlaceHolderQuickLaunchBottom" content-place holder in your custom master page and comment out the DIV tag as shown below.

`<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderQuickLaunchBottom" runat="server">
                    <%--<div class="ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox">
                        <SharePoint:ClusteredSPLinkButton
                            runat="server"
                            id="idNavLinkViewAll"
                            PermissionsString="ViewFormPages"
                            NavigateUrl="~site/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx"
                            Text="<%$Resources:wss,AllSiteContentMore%>"
                            accesskey="<%$Resources:wss,quiklnch_allcontent_AK%>"
                            CssClass="ms-core-listMenu-item ms-core-listMenu-heading" />
                    </div>--%>
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>`

Comment: Nderon..that hides the Site Content !  I want the Site Content to displau on a Main Page.